# How to understand the symmetric property of Dirichlet distribution and its 0 results of integration with log function?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

I'm trying to do such a integration.
$$\int \log \left(\prod_{k=1}^K p_k^{\alpha_k-1}\right) \operatorname{Dir}(\mathbf{p} \mid \boldsymbol{\alpha}) d \mathbf{p}$$
And the ChatGPT tells me that integration equals 0.
$$\int \log \left(\prod_{k=1}^K p_k^{\alpha_k-1}\right) \operatorname{Dir}(\mathbf{p} \mid \boldsymbol{\alpha}) d \mathbf{p} = 0$$
because the symmetric property of dirichlet distribution.

This is its interpretation.

The Dirichlet distribution is defined on the K-dimensional simplex, which is a multi-dimensional generalization of the interval [0, 1]. The symmetry here refers to the fact that the distribution is symmetric with respect to the K−1-dimensional subspace.

I'm little bit confusing.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4Ig9.png)

For such a distribution, is it symmetric along the 1-d simplex (i.e. lines)?

Is this equation correct and how to understand this?

Thanks for all possible answers.

Comment: That is not correct.  The formula for entropy is clearly visible on [Wikipedia page on Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution).